# How can I check if a Value exists in a Concurrent Array/Map/List of Objects in order to prevent adding and link new to the existing one

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I need to process Video, which is an object inside a Job object.There can only be one Job per original video. When a Video is processed, it is saved as another Video object inside that Job.       I want to be able to detect whether that Video is already being processed:
If it is:

- It must not add it to the queue
- Once the original Video is processed, the processed video must be sent to all who added or tried to add that same Video

If it is not:

- Add it to the queue

```
public class Job {
    private Video o_video;
    private Video coded_video;
    
    public Job(Video v) {
        o_video = v;
        coded_video = null;
    }
    
    public Video extractOriginal() {
        return o_video;
    }
    public void addCodedVideo(Video vCod) {
        synchronized(this) {
            coded_video = vCod;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
        return;
    }
    public Video extractCodedVideo() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(this) {
            while(coded_video ==null) {
                this.wait();
            }
        }
        return coded_video;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using wait and notify is generally a code smell, and it doesn't really seem to be helping here.  I would expect a ConcurrentMap of video names/IDs to jobs.

Comment: Exactly, that will solve the issue, the problem. The wait and notify is for other purposes, or at least thats how it is intended to be. How can I save video contained in every job into a ConcurrentMap and then check if another new job is trying to place its own video in the jobs queue?

Comment: Use `putIfAbsent` on the map with the video key.  If and only if it succeeds by returning null, the current task "wins the race" and should be responsible for enqueuing the job for that video.